# How to execute multiple reduce jobs with one mapper using bash file in Hadoop using Python as the base?

Tags: unix, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

[bash file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dQf.png)

I formatted the mapper and the reducer to be the same so I can skip the mapping steps and just continue to reduce it. IN this case I am only doing two reduce jobs. It works fine using Unix piping commands. However, I need this to work using a bash file.

I've tried listing it twice:

```
    -reducer "python3 reducer.py"\
    -reducer "python3 reducer.py"
```

and tried piping inside the bash

```
  -reducer "python3 reducer.py | python3 reducer.py"
```

I also tried some other combinations. Some broke period, some created wrong output. I feel like there is a solution out there but can't get it do work... I am using MobaXterm to work in Hadoop.

[piping commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0tG6.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code. Please show the command you tried with the resulting error and/or output.

Answer (score 0):

No, Hadoop Streaming cannot do pipes. If you want to run the reducer output through itself, then collect the data within the file into a list rather than printing, and use a loop to re-process the data.

Alternatively, use a MapReduce `Combiner`.

Comment: OK, so how does that loop look like inside the bash file? Right now it is:
#!/bin/bash
hadoop jar $HADOOP_STREAMING \
        -input /user/user/M.csv \
        -output /user/user/outputP4 \
        -file mapper.py \
        -file reducer.py \
        -mapper "python3 mapper.py" \
        -reducer "python3 reducer.py" \

Comment: You would do the loop directly in the `reducer.py` code. You dont need bash.